# How to create a top level namespace in javascript

Tags: javascript, web

So now I have 3 javascript files. item.js, items.js, main.js. Their structure is like

```html
var item = (function(){
        //some functions inside and return statement
})();

same goes for main and items.
now the hierarchy of the files are, as I understood,
window.item, window.items, window.main
but I want to change it to 

window.todo.items
window.todo.item
window.todo.main
```

I have searched a lot on namespaces but couldn't find the answer. Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: window.todo = {  item: item};

Comment: Declare window.todo = {}; so that todo is an empty object,   then declare window.todo.item = (function(){})(); here item is an attrib of todo object  same goes to other 2 files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: there are no namespaces in JavaScript. You can somewhat simulate namespaces using objects.

First you have to make sure that your `todo` object does exist. (You cannot bulk-create properties)

```
window.todo = {};
```

Then you can add properties to that `todo` object:

```
window.todo.item = (function () { ... })();
// or
window.todo.item = item;
```

You can also initialize properties while creating the `todo` object:

```
window.todo = {
    item: (function { ... })()
};
// or
window.todo = {
    item: item
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, first you'd need to define todo

```
window.todo = {};
```

Then you'd need to add each file's object to it

```
window.todo.item = (function(){
    //some functions inside and return statement
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically js is depend upon the **priority of the js file,**
so make sure that, decendent file don't have the depency on above file,